# What is this pattern and what are the missing characters?

Tags: pattern

> <, (?), =, >, (?), >

Hints:

> 1) a sequence,
>
> 2) the characters serve as symbols

Comment: This question's simplicity is infuriatingly unnerving! (not referring to the answer hehe)

Comment: Are the commas, spaces, brackets, and question marks part of the sequence and there are some missing ones somewhere, or is this a 6-character sequence and the (?) represents the location of the missing ones?

Comment: Are the characters the same? And is [sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence) relevant?

Comment: Given the unspecific question, we could also answer that "the pattern is a sequence" and the missing characters are "(?)".

Comment: Or its just a comma separated list of symbols, missing some commas: <, (, ?, ), =, >, (, ?, ), >

Answer (score 9):

I think the missing characters are

> "<" and ">"

because

> each symbol corresponds to the relation of its position (1-6) to the number 3. So the complete sequence would be <, <, =, >, >, >.

Comment: Noooo...noooo nooooo nooooo

Comment: @user18447 If you have to reject a simple answer that fits all the clues, that almost certainly means your question needs to be narrowed down more.

Comment: Well. For simple is simple. But none of the clues in fact

Comment: He did not assign specific meanings to the characters but the relation of them to a chosen one. He guessed one means an undefined number and the others might define sg similar what they look like: more or less. This whole thing is a packet of inconsistency☺

Comment: @user18447: Nothing is inconsistent about his answer at all. The number 3 is not undefined, and the answer fits all the clues.

Answer (score 7):

My guess is that the missing characters are:

> " < " and " > "

it symbolizes:

> Media buttons: "<<" rewind, "=" pause, ">" play, ">>" fast forward

Comment: pause is vertical stripes, though?

Comment: haha yeah, but just a guess